# Dialogflow Actions on Google return to followup intent after fallback intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have these intents:
[image: intents screenshot]

My intent `setup-selectImage` is an Actions on Google card carousel. When I select a card, `setup-selectTerritory` gets triggered, which works.

Now I'm trying to get the fallback intent working properly. When I trigger it by giving the assistant a random input, which is not accepted by the followup intent `setup-selectTerritory`, it will ask the user to repeat his input with a value which is accepted.

However when the user inputs an accepted value, after the fallback intent was triggered, it doesn't work anymore. It keeps triggering the fallback intent rather than the `setup-selectTerritory` intent.

Comment: Do you set the output context of the fallback to the same output context for the setup-selectImage intent?

Comment: Yes, I did! `setup-selectImage - fallback` has `setup-selectImage-followup` as input and output context. But I'm using a webhook. Do I have to set the output context in the webhook?

Comment: Setting context in the webhook isn't mandatory, it does give you more flexibilty if you decide to do it in the webhook. You should choose between setting it only in Dialogflow or only in the webhook, doing both can be quite messy. Regarding your problem, if the context is set correctly, it is going to be difficult the find the issue without any additional information, could you add more info about the intents?